# Dictionary help in Julia - creating dictionary from text file

Tags: dictionary, julia

I'm attempting to create a library from the contents of a text file in Julia for use in a bioinformatics problem. The file is formatted like this:

```
UUU F      CUU L      AUU I      GUU V
UUC F      CUC L      AUC I      GUC V
...
```

I want to make a dictionary where the key is the 3 letter part (the codon), and the entry is the one letter part (the amino acid). I'm able to pull out the right components with grep:

```
for m in eachmatch(r"([AUGC]{3,3})\s([A-Z])", file)
    codon, aa = m.captures
```

If I print `codon` and `aa` in this loop, I get out the correct output (all the codon's, all the aa's) but I can't figure out how to put it into a dictionary. If I do: `codons = {codon => aa}` at the end of the loop, I end up with a dictionary that only contains the last entry.

I'm sure the syntax is something really obvious, but I'm a biologist, not a programmer, so my reading of [the documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=dictionaries#associative-collections) isn't getting me anywhere. It says:

> Given a dictionary D, the syntax D[x] returns the value of key x (if it exists) or throws an error, and D[x] = y stores the key-value pair x => y in D (replacing any existing value for the key x).

But I tried `codons[codon] = aa` at the end of the loop (I initiated the dictionary with `codons = {}` before the loop), but I get the error:

```
no method setindex!(Array{Any,1},SubString{UTF8String},SubString{UTF8String})
at In[35]:5
 in anonymous at no file:4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Evidently, I'm not initiating the dictionary correctly. If I do `codons = {"blah" => "blahblah"}` at the beginning, the loop works and fills in correctly. So a modified question: how do you initiate empty libraries?

EDIT2: Minimal not working example:

```
file = open(readall, "rna_codons.txt")
codons = {}
for m in eachmatch(r"([AUGC]{3,3})\s([A-Z])", file)
    codon, aa = m.capture
    codons[codon] = aa
end
```

Comment: Would you edit your original post and include a Minimal (Not)Working Example?  Also what version/platform are you using?  A small example on my pre-0.3 version Linux box seems to work fine.  Perhaps you just need `codons[codon] = aa` *in* your loop?

Comment: ... and `codons = Dict()` *before* your loop?

Comment: Yup, the `codons = Dict()` is what I was missing - think I was trying to initiate the dictionary using python syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize a Minimal Working Example (MWE) for your case of reading your formatted text file into a Julia [Dict](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=associative%20array#associative-collections)...

```
file = open(readall, "rna_codons.txt")
codons = Dict()
for m in eachmatch(r"([AUGC]{3,3})\s([A-Z])", file)
    codon, aa = m.capture
    codons[codon] = aa
end
```

N.B.:  If the file is very large, there is likely a faster way of generating your `Dict`.

***EDIT***

Given your apparent text file format, here's another way to create your `Dict`.  I made no tests to determine any performance loss/gain.

```
condon_array = open(readdlm, "rna_codons.txt")
condons = Dict{ASCIIString,ASCIIString}(condon_array[:,1:2:end][:],condon_array[:,2:2:end][:])
```

N.B.:  If you use it, better check it for correctness.

Comment: This file is not very large, but I'd love to hear suggestions. Since I'm just learning programming (and the whole point of going through these problems is to learn), I might as well learn best practices rather than getting into bad habits.

Comment: In general, regular expression matching can be slow.  If your text file has only valid text separated by consistent delimiters, you may want to have a look at something like [`readdlm`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=readdlm#Base.readdlm).  You may also want to read the [performance tips](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/) and play with some [profiling](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/profile/)