# Julia dictionary "key not found" only when using loop

Tags: dictionary, key, julia

Still trying to figure out this [problem](http://rosalind.info/problems/prot/) (I was [having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236030/dictionary-help-in-julia-creating-dictionary-from-text-file) building a dictionary, but managed to get that working thanks to [rickhg12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374/rickhg12hs)).

Here's my current code:

```
#open files with codon:amino acid pairs, initiate dictionary:
file = open(readall, "rna_codons.txt")
seq = open(readall, "rosalind_prot.txt")
codons = {"UAA" => "stop", "UGA" => "stop", "UAG" => "stop"}

#generate dictionary entries using pairs from file:
for m in eachmatch(r"([AUGC]{3,3})\s([A-Z])\s", file)
    codon, aa = m.captures
    codons[codon] = aa
end
```

All of that code seems to work as intended. At this point, I have the dictionary I want, and the right keys point to the right entries. If I just do `print(codons["AUG"])` for example, it prints `'M'`, which is the correct output. Now I want to scan through a string in the second file, and for every 3 letters, pull out the entry referenced in the dictionary and add it to the `prot` string. So I tried:

```
for m in eachmatch(r"([AUGC]{3,3})", seq)
    amac = codons[m.captures]
    prot = "$prot$amac"
end
```

But this kicks out the error `key not found: ["AUG"]`. I know the key exists, because I can print `codons["AUG"]` and it returns the proper entry, so why can't it find that key when it's in the loop?

Comment: What version of Julia are you using? My suspicion is that this may be the difference between indexing with a substring and a string. You may have a version where match captures are substrings but we hadn't yet made sure that substrings hash the same as an equal string value.

Comment: I'm on the current release (0.2.1), but I'm using iJulia notebook if that changes anything.

Comment: If you want to stick with Regex's and if the Regex is to changed to `r"[AUGC]{3,3}"`, and `m.captures` is changed to `m.match`, does it work for you?  Also, I'm not sure how `prot` get its start, but does `prot *= amac` work for you?

Comment: I'm not married to Regex's, that's just what I know to use. I'm still trying to look through the stuff you mentioned in the other thread, but this whole thing is a side project and I haven't made a ton of progress.

Comment: But... Changing the Regex to what you suggest works! I didn't build the entire library right because the first Regex search didn't make the last entry (because there was no space after the last entry), but that's easily fixed. 

 `prot *=amac` also works, I just wasn't aware of that syntax, thanks for the help!